# SharePoint 2013 List Item

Tags: sharepoint-addin

When adding a list item, a prompt the screenshot below.
[image]

As per checking from the permission level, we have the same permission which is full control. Why does this show?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Go to list setting, Permissions, and see which permissions you have

Comment: He have a full control and a contribute permission on the list settings.

Answer (score 1):

In **AppManifest.xml** file, add Permission for your app.

If you are performing CRUD operations on List Or Library then provide necessary Permission based on scope.

eg: We are using Manage Permission for developer on Site Collection Scope.

Reference snap: 
[image]

You can get more info about app permissions from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your information. This only happens for 1 user. Me and others can add to the list.